# VS Code - Why vscode doesn't display html tag attributes

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

I use VS Code for HTML editing, but when I enter the tag, it does not display its attributes and even when I add the attribute I want, it does not recognize it.
I did the following, but none of them worked:

1-I installed the relevant extensions(HTML CSS Support , HTML Snippets , HTML Boilerplates , etc).
2-After I added a tag, press Ctrl+Space.
3-restart my machine.
4-reinstall VS code.

(I entered the css, html code below and the name of my css file is "style post.css" and it is in the folder where my HTML file is located).

I did everything I could, I would be happy if someone could guide me.

```css
h2.head1{
    color:red ;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Post</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style_post.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Scrambled Eggs </h1>
    <p>
    eggs are one of my favorite foods.here is recipe for deliciously rich scrambled eggs.<br>
    </p>
    <h2 class:"head1">Ingredients</h2>
    
    <ul>
        <li>
        2eggs
        </li><li>
        1 tbs butter
        </li><li>
        2 tbs cream
        </li>
    </ul>
    
    <h2>Method</h2>
    
    <ol>
        <li>
        Melt butter in a frying pan over a medium heat.
        </li><li>
        Gently mix the eggs and cream in the bowl.
        </li><li>
        once bottle has melt add cream and eggs.
        </li><li>
        Using the spatula fold the eggs from the edge of the pan to the center every 20 secend(as if you are making an omelette)
        </li><li>
        When the eggs are still moist remove from the heat(it will continue to cook on the plate until served)
        </li>
    </ol>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either have a typo or you have to look up on how to set attributes in HTML: You do this with this syntax: `attribute="value"` and not with `:`

So in your case you should have used `class="head1"`

```css
h2.head1{
    color:red ;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Post</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style_post.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Scrambled Eggs </h1>
    <p>
    eggs are one of my favorite foods.here is recipe for deliciously rich scrambled eggs.<br>
    </p>
    <h2 class="head1">Ingredients</h2>
    
    <ul>
        <li>
        2eggs
        </li><li>
        1 tbs butter
        </li><li>
        2 tbs cream
        </li>
    </ul>
    
    <h2>Method</h2>
    
    <ol>
        <li>
        Melt butter in a frying pan over a medium heat.
        </li><li>
        Gently mix the eggs and cream in the bowl.
        </li><li>
        once bottle has melt add cream and eggs.
        </li><li>
        Using the spatula fold the eggs from the edge of the pan to the center every 20 secend(as if you are making an omelette)
        </li><li>
        When the eggs are still moist remove from the heat(it will continue to cook on the plate until served)
        </li>
    </ol>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You are right, I should have used "=".
But you have no idea why it does not display attributes itself?

Comment: Maybe open up a follow up question? I have no clue what you mean with `doesn't display attribute itself` ... attributes are not displayed, that's not what attributes are for. So what do you mean?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "that's not what attributes are for." what ?
For example, "class", "id" are attributes for the "h1" tag that you have to display these attributes when you write the tag and then enter a space. Sorry, if I do not explain well, I am new to html. and what is "follow up"?

Comment: Follow up means a new question, so that more people can try to help you :) I still don't know where you want to display these attributes? In the browser? Somewhere else? Attributes are not getting rendered in the browser, they are just for styling and functionality.

Comment: I am learning html. For example, I am going to select a specific tag from the h1 tags and change its color in the css code, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the user: cloned
I was able to find the answer to the second part of my question which was "why vscode does not automatically open some tags with its attrebute names".

I said maybe someone has a problem similar to mine and can help him/her:)

According to the figure, we have to select html in the bottom right corner of the page, and my problem was that the language was django html.

[image]